# Regular Expression to Remove HTML Number Codes

Tags: regex

I would like to remove special HTML characters using regular Expressions.

`&#8482;` is the trade mark symbol - that's okay to stay.

But if the length of numbers between `&#` and `;` is greater than 4 digits, it needs to be removed.

For example: `&#128527;` is a smiley face - needs to be filtered out.

This line of code is not working `$article =~ s/&#\d{4,};//;`

Comment: why would that be useful? Usually, you can just embed unicode directly these days.

Comment: Side note: Those things are called "numeric character references". Also you should usually state a language or library in your tags because regular expressions come in many flavours with wildly different capabilities  (I'm guessing Perl here?).

Answer (score 2):

- Use the **g**lobal flag to replace **all instances** of a pattern, rather than just the first.
- If you want to replace instances with **greater than** 4 digits, then quantify with a minimum of **5**.

```
$article =~ s/&#\d{5,};//g;
```

Comment: Fixed - the 5 (vs my 4) was my main mistake. Along with the greedy g flag.  Thank you!

Comment: No problem.  If you found that my answer answered your question, would you mind marking it as such?  If it didn't, that's fine, too.